# regexp to match specific query

Tags: regex, bash

I have a PostgreSQL query, which gives the following kind of outputs:

```
<number> | [<empty_body>] <number> [<some_stuff>,"id":<ID>]
```

for instance

```
5 | [] 7 ["id":6]
```

so
I want to get:

```
 5 "" and 7 "6"
```

or

```
8 | ["id" 9]  15 ["id" 18]
```

Here I want to get:

```
8 "9" and 15 "18"
```

How can I write some regexp which will return `<number>` and "id" if it is exists.

Comment: do you need to return second <number> and <ID> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output pattern is sth like this:

```
 (\d+)\s*\|?\s*\[(?:"id"\:?\s*|)(|\d+)\]
```

Find  in first matched group and  in second one. [See Online](https://regex101.com/r/x3CFFb/1)

```
Full match  0-6 `5 | []`
Group 1.    0-1 `5`
Group 2.    5-5 ``
Match 2
Full match  7-17    `7 ["id":6]`
Group 1.    7-8 `7`
Group 2.    15-16   `6`
Match 3
Full match  22-34   `8 | ["id" 9]`
Group 1.    22-23   `8`
Group 2.    32-33   `9`
Match 4
Full match  36-48   `15 ["id" 18]`
Group 1.    36-38   `15`
Group 2.    45-47   `18`
```

If arrays contains some other key-values, try this regex:

```
(\d+)\s*\|?\s*\[.*?(?:"id"\:?\s*|)(|\d+\b)[^\d]*?\]
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/x3CFFb/2)